# Find Updates does not find latest Joomla core update

Tags: joomla-3.4, one-click-updates

My site is @ Joomla v3.4.8. Today I received an email announcement that Joomla v3.5.1 was released.

If I go to Extensions > Manage > Update > Find Updates, no updates are found.

I do get a message saying:

> Warning Some update sites are disabled. You may want to check the
>   Update Sites Manager.

In Update Sites Manager, Joomla Core is enabled.

Help appreciated.

Comment: check  this -> https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Updating_from_an_existing_version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Joomla core updates go under **Components > Joomla! Update**. If it does not appear the new update click on the "Clear Cache" button and all should be fixed.

**Extensions > Manage > Update** refers only to components/plugins/module..

Also check this article that explains how to fix the [Joomla! Update component missing from admin menu](https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_Update_Missing_in_from_Admin_Menu).

Comment: Great. Thanks Nicola. Unfortunately Joomla! Update is not visible under Components. The Joomla! Update component in Extensions > Manage [looks like this](http://i112.photobucket.com/albums/n180/SRD001/update.png).

Comment: That's strange, because the Joomla! Update component should be on version 3.0.0. Did you start the website from Joomla 3.4.8 or have you already done updates in the past? Also check under global configuration/Joomla Update if update channel is set to "default".

Comment: I'm pretty sure I start at something less than 3.4.8. Yes, update channel is set to default. When I logged in the other day, the first page I saw in admin had a message saying 3.5.1 was available, and I installed this okay.

Comment: Good to know you've solved the problem, probably it was a bug in version 3.5.0, Joomla! Update component has been updated removing any mootools dependencies.